# Weasprint and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, flask, weasyprint

Does anybody have any experience rendering web pages in weasyprint that are styled using twitter Bootstrap?  Whenever I try, the html renders completely unstyled as if there was no css applied to it.

Comment: Maybe used print styles, try as alternative `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: An example of what you were trying to style would have made this a much better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  When I declared the style sheet i set media="screen", I removed that tag element and it seemed to fix it.  Further research indicated I could also declare a separate stylesheet and set media="print".